# How to display data coming from an object in the directive link function angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am calling data from an object which is in the main controller. And it is displaying perfectly fine. I have a requirement now which I have to move the object in the directive's link function, and still render it the way it was rendering before.

Here is the main HTML code.

```
<cs-tooltip id="cs-tooltip" testingtooltip="firsttooltip" testfunc="secondBut()" ng-show="showtooltip"></cs-tooltip>
```

Here is the templateUrl code  of the directive:

```
<div id="cs-tooltip-title">{{testingtooltip.title}}</div>
```

And here is an example of the object that I have:

```
$scope.firsttooltip = {
    content: 'Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. Score derived. ',
    title: "Threat Score",
}
```

The object I am using is pretty complex, I have just simplified it here for understanding the concept. I am trying to make a link function in the directive like this and the data doesn't show up.

```
link: function($scope){
        //the same object here
    }
```

Comment: have you declared a scope property to hold testingtooltip in your directive? scope: {testingtooltip: '='}

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I can only think of a problem that can be fixed with timeout.

If you have a directive scope:

```
scope: {
  testingtooltip: '='
}
```

In the link function you can try:

```
link: function($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.testingtooltip);
  });
}
```